# How to use esm module in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am importing this in `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/walletlink"></script>
```

Now, in my `script.js`, I want to use it, but it fails with:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Is there any way to be able to use it in jQuery without too much overhead ?

Comment: I don’t think you can use the version distributed by unpkg, because the way it’s composed it’s distributed as an esmodule and you will need to manually compile it.

Comment: thanks Terry. do you know any tool that can do this without going through webpack and overkill ?

Comment: Unfortunately you need an intermediate build step. If you don’t want to use webpack you can consider using a faster and simpler bundler, like rollup, but you cannot avoid it.

Comment: Maybe skypack works for you: https://www.skypack.dev/